# C# and Active Directory

Tags: c#, ldap

Is there a way to retrieve/get new users (latest or new user created) from Active Directory, preferably periodically using C# and LDAP? I have tried a SharePoint Time Job, but It will not work for me. I'm using a C# Windows Service.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes". What have you tried so far?

Comment: _"but It will_ (not?) _work for me"_.

Comment: I have tried to use the whenChanged and whenModified, I'm just not sure what to compare these dates to.

Comment: Like for instance I know AD has a CreatedDate "field" I could use LDAP to query that date or the ones I have mentioned above, my issue is I have dates, but I have got no idea what I should compare these dates with.

Comment: @Thabo Why not just `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`?